DISPLAY variable in systemd user session
I'm trying to write a simple systemd user service that should be able to run a GUI, so DISPLAY must be set. Whenever the service is started automatically during login, DISPLAY is missing. When I restart it afterwards (systemctl --user restart testdisplay), everything works fine.
I'm trying on different distributions/desktops, even Fedora/GNOME doesn't work.
/etc/xdg/systemd/user/testdisplay.service
[Unit]
Description=Test
PartOf=graphical-session.target
After=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/systemctl --user show-environment
ExecStart=env


[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

After writing that file, I enabled it globally with systemctl --user enable testdisplay.service.
Any advise?
systemctl --user show-environment |grep DIS
DISPLAY=:0.0

Regards, Bernhard

Maybe it is not a good idea to have it in systemd. For sure it is not what I mean for service. The clock in my desktop is not run by systemd. Consider to use autostart or session management. Note: I do not know the kind of your service, so it may be good on systemd (and see answer), e.g. for POS, but consider that you will know only first display, so your solution may fail in many cases.

@GiacomoCatenazzi: Half of a typical GNOME or KDE desktop is run by systemd – it was not the initial use case, but eventually it shifted towards --user services being suitable for that purpose. (As soon as the session dbus-daemon became a "user bus", it already became necessary for DEs or login managers to upload environment variables to it, and when dbus-daemon was taught how to spawn its services via systemd, the same became necessary to do with systemd --user in general... so now it's often the easiest way to inject something into a graphical session.)

When the user logs in, default.target comes up immediately.  Your graphical session might still be starting at this point.  It's too early to run graphical programs.  Use graphical-session.target instead.  That only comes up when the the desktop is ready.  See man systemd.special for details.


Whenever the service is started automatically during login, DISPLAY is missing. When I restart it afterwards (systemctl --user restart testdisplay), everything works fine.

That's the expected result.
Your systemd user manager is not started as part of the graphical session – it is merely triggered by the start of it, but in all regards it runs as a completely detached process, very much like a cron job. All "graphical session" environment variables are only imported into it after the PAM session setup has been completed.
Roughly, the timeline is like this:
GDM calls PAM authenticate (password verification)
GDM calls PAM account (authorization/accounting)
GDM calls PAM open_session (session preparation)
   pam_systemd calls systemd-logind CreateSession
      systemd-logind calls systemd to start user@<uid>.service
         user@<uid> calls its own PAM account/open_session
         user@<uid> spawns systemd --user
            systemd --user starts default.target
               your service is launched as part of default.target
            systemd --user indicates "Done" when basic.target is reached [1]
         user@<uid> indicates "Started"
      systemd-logind returns call
   pam_systemd returns
GDM calls systemd-user SetEnvironment to import DISPLAY, &c.
GDM spawns gnome-session
   gnome-session does the rest

[1] the rest of default.target may continue to start asynchronously

As you can see, not only is your service triggered too early, the mechanisms are built such that putting it in default.target will guarantee that it will start too early. (That is, it isn't even the kind of race condition that you could solve with "sleep 60" – even if you tried to do that, that would just delay the thing you're waiting for.)
The correct way to do this is either a) by moving your service into a different trigger .target, for example, graphical-session.target, or b) by having the app be started by the older XDG ~/.config/autostart mechanism instead.
(These days the latter may actually be implemented in terms of a systemd "xdg-autostart-generator" that puts services in graphical-session.target, which is a good confirmation that it's the right .target to use.)
In the past (before the aforementioned .target was added as default), I used to simply systemctl --user start graphical.target & from my ~/.xprofile or ~/.xinitrc, and I still do that on smaller systems that don't run GNOME.

Thanks. I thought I tried that, but obviously I didn't. However, it  doesn't work in my Xfce/Arch setup out of the box.
I decided to implement the XDG autostart way which works flawlessly.

Pass the Value Before Starting the Service
Try something Like:
[Service]
Environment="$DISPLAY=<some value>"
# Test that DISPLAY was set
ExecStart=<your command>

Anything more complicated would require starting a script as seen in Setting Environment Variables for systemd Services as argument passing and string expansion aren't well supported in systemd
